# Error on exporting Advanced Pricing

Tags: magento2.4, export, advanced-pricing

I'm new on setting up Magento. I'm currently on 2.4.6-p2, running on Apache 2.4.58, php 8.1, MySQL 8.0.35-cll-lve.

I have a setting of 2 Web Site, both having 1 Store View.

When I tried to export the Advanced Pricing (no matter in partial or full list), it will prompt an error as follow:

> Error during export process occurred
>
> Error during export process occurred. Please check logs for detail

I've tried to check on the error logs, on the system.log shows only a line

> main.CRITICAL: Something went wrong while export process. There is no
> data for the export. [] []

And there's no record in exception.log or debug.log

Tried to look for solution on this and found a temporaily fix at https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/461009ef7492cae1ca17183fac5b26d142b6e01f but the file content looks pretty different to what I'm having.

Comment: Suddenly I can export the advanced pricing table, no clues on the reason